# Speeding up MYSQL union query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having difficulties speeding up this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT create_full_name FROM flow UNION
SELECT DISTINCT change_full_name FROM flow UNION
SELECT DISTINCT release_full_name FROM flow UNION
SELECT DISTINCT reject_full_name FROM flow
order by create_full_name
```

The query takes 24.9 seconds to return 419 rows.

Keep in mind that in my flow table, I have 2,948,726 rows.

Thanks!

Comment: As well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables, questions about query optimization ALWAYS required the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Comment: usage of `union all` can speed up thing, but only if you can guarantee that tables contain unique values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating four indexes:

```
flow(create_full_name)
flow(change_full_name)
flow(release_full_name)
flow(reject_full_name)
```

MySQL should use these indexes for the `select distinct`s.  Then the final distinct for `union` should be pretty fast.

Note:  Using `select distinct` for the subqueries should be a good idea, even though it is redundant (because `union` removes distincts).  They allow the optimizer to optimize elimination of duplicates *within* each subquery before bringing the data together.